# Online Course for Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

I noticed there are some good undergraduate calculus and linear algebra courses online (eg edx, MIT open courseware, Khan Academy, etc) and I'm taking some myself. But I'm now thinking about going the extra step afterwards and tackling Real Analysis.

Are there any similar good online courses for introductory Real Analysis? I seem plenty of helpful recommendations for texts for self study, but no high quality video lectures outside of some stuff on youtube. Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't have reputation to answer this, but Harvard Extension has a two-course sequence on Linear Algebra and Real Analysis: https://www.extension.harvard.edu/course-catalog/courses/linear-algebra-and-real-analysis-i/15176?subjects=Mathematics (fall) + https://www.extension.harvard.edu/course-catalog/courses/linear-algebra-and-real-analysis-ii/25125?subjects=Mathematics (spring). https://www.extension.harvard.edu/course-catalog/courses/mathematics-for-computation-and-data-science/25129 also includes real analysis.

Answer (score 7):

This might not have very high video quality, but I guess it's something to watch especially if you are focused on learning Real Analysis from the basics.

http://analysisyawp.blogspot.ca

Comment: Francis Su's lectures are top notch.

Comment: This is really good! I am on lecture 5. But, the problem here is lack of exercises.

Comment: Perhaps the assignments from the MIT course could be a good supplement: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-100c-real-analysis-fall-2012/pages/syllabus/